# Font options in the Paralist* compactdesc environment

Tags: paralist

I'm using the compactdesc environment from paralist as a kludge for tightly packed paragraphs with a hanging first line.  In truth, the use of the description environment is suited to what I'm doing (list of names plus the institute they're from), so having the label (i.e. the names) be in a different font family of some kind isn't a bad move, it's specifically the use of boldface that I'm trying to get away from, and maybe adjust it to something else - like sans serif or whatever.  Once I know how, I'll figure out the rest myself.

I'm just trying to remove the bold from the label - or adjust it at all in any way - and can't find anywhere online where it's well described (and ideally with a copypasta-friendly example).

Basically;

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paralist}
    ...
\begin{document}

\begin{compactdesc}
    \raggedright
\item [Something]. Short description.
\item [Something else].  A very long line which may or may not run over to the next line and which isn't hyphen-split thanks to ragged edges
\item [And another thing]. Short description.
\end{compactdesc}

\end{document}
```

What I'm looking for is for the [Something] parts to not be bold, and the code for this will almost definitely be in the preamble somewhere - some kind of a \setcompactdesc{font=\normalfont} sort of a deal (except that command doesn't work).

Any help?

Comment: Could you please make your example compilable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know well enough `paralist`, but you can easily obtain this result with `enumitem`. Example with `scshape` as label font:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{description}[nosep, font=\mdseries\scshape]
  \raggedright
  \item [Something]. Short description.
  \item [Something else]. A very long line which may or may not run over to the next line and which isn't hyphen-split thanks to ragged edges
  \item [And another thing]. Short description.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: B.t.w., the dot should be *inside* the item.

Answer (score 0):

The `paralist` [documentation](https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/paralist/paralist.pdf) has it in its 4th page.

[image: img]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{paralist}

\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{%
\hspace\labelsep\scshape #1}


\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]
\begin{compactdesc}\raggedright
  \item [Something.] Short description.
  \item [Something else.]  A very long line which may or may not run over to the next line and which isn't hyphen-split thanks to ragged edges.
  \item [And another thing.] Short description.
\end{compactdesc}

\end{document}
```

[image: img]

...with the dot *inside* the item as @Bernard suggested.